# What does websocket error 520 mean in coinbase API?

Tags: websocket, coinbase-api

I'm using the coinbase websocket API to read order book opens and closes from a node process running in a container in amazon fargate.

Sometimes, when this container starts up, it gets an error saying "Unexpected server response: 520"

This error code is not documented in the API list of error codes. Also, the websocket node module (coinbase-pro-node) is marked as "archive" on GitHub, but is still linked-to by the Coinbase developer documentation as the current version.

What does this error mean (other than "some server problem" coming from the 5xx series) ?